# MongoDB: aggregation $lookup with lossy data type

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections:

- cats
- balls

"cats" collection has documents with key "ballId" of type `string`

"balls" collection has documents with key "_id" of type `ObjectId`

An $lookup inside an aggregation is able to retrieve results if the join is done on keys with the same data type. However in my case, "ballId" and "_id" are of different types. This code retrieves the cats but doesn't retrieve the related balls:

```
collection('cats').aggregate([
  { $match:{} },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "balls",
      localField: "ballId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "balls"
    }
  }
]);
```

How can I use $lookup with lossy data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$lookup` with [pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-concise-correlated-subquery-with--lookup) stage.

Join both collections by converting `balls`' `_id` to string (`$toString`) and next compare both values as string (`$eq`).

```
db.cats.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "balls",
      let: {
        ballId: "$ballId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                {
                  "$toString": "$_id"
                },
                "$$ballId"
              ]
            },
            
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "balls"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eb7LlWuUL4n)